# Javascript, Can I stretch text vertically

Tags: javascript

Can I Stretch text in javascript? I dont want the font bigger because that makes it appear bolder than smaller text beside it, I just want to stretch the text vertically so its kind of deformed . This would be one div id and then normal text beside it would be another div id. Any ideas?

Thanks, -Matthew

Note: I asked this question originally in the CSS section and all anyone could recommend was horizontal stretching by setting the spacing negative.

Comment: you can do this with canvas, but i don't think with javascript

Comment: Can you put your text into an image? You can create the illusion of stretching by putting it in an image and playing with the width and height of the image.

Comment: @Rob - Thanks, I might have to use an image and deform that?

Comment: @NullRef , Yes but as soon as you use images they print, (hardcopy) differently on macs vs. pcs

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059130/waving-text-on-canvas

Comment: @Matthew905 - I totally agree. It is totally a hack.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'no' since you cannot access the glyph of a font as a graphic object. You might be able to using HTML5's canvas object, but that is not widely supported (yet.)

Comment: not widely supported?  Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE9, excanvas (IE 6/7/8)

Comment: @cwolves, Sure, in current versions, but how many *installed* browsers do you suppose support HTML5?

Comment: um, 99% of all installs of FF, every install of chrome, 99% of all safari installs and with excanvas, 99% of all IE installs (about 10% without since that's roughly the current IE9 base)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this link about [cross-browser CSS transforms](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/) will help?  It appears that you can specify a transformation matrix to render any (?) HTML element and there are built-in functions for scaling and skewing, etc.